# Каков наиболее полный синтаксис вопроса, требующего описание сущности?

Tags: синтаксический-анализ, естественный-язык

Как можно наиболее полно описать вопросительное предложение, спрашивающее (упрощённо), что такое "сущность"? Какие могут быть подводные камни при обработке таких запросов?

На данный момент в голову приходят только следующие варианты:

- Что такое (возможно указательное местоимение) "сущность"?
- Кто такой(ая) (возможно указательное местоимение) "сущность"?
- Что (возможно прилагательное) ты можешь сказать (рассказать, поведать) о (об) (возможно указательное местоимение) "сущность"?
- (Переспрашивая) "сущность" (или относительное местоимение)?

Цель - распознание запроса информации о некой сущности и определение её идентификатора при поверхностном семантическом анализе.

**UPD (из комментария)**

Видимо, недостаточно точно сформулировал вопрос. Подразумевается, что человек пытается узнать о сущности (что и пытаемся распознать), а не наоборот. Т.е., например, под идентификатором подразумевается то, как человек описал сущность. А вопросы (искомые) подразумевают синтаксические конструкции на естественном языке, подразумевающие запрос информации о сущности и позволяющие вычленить из себя её идентификатор.

**UPD 1**

Вычленение, скорее всего, будет происходить при применении шаблона "от 'что такое ' до '?' - идентификатор, за исключением (указательное местоимение)". Рассмотрению подлежат любые методы вычленения идентификатора.

Comment: Искусственный интеллект разрабатываете?

Comment: Систему ответа на вопросы с поверхностным анализом (без самообучения).